# How do I create a formula that pulls data from multiple objects into a new object that will continually updated?

Tags: formula

I am working with inventory.  Currently we are using object 1 as the inventory object, in which we would like it to update each item using a formula that will pull additions and subtractions from inventory in objects 2 and 3 respectively.  I have been able to write a formula that will update using the first entry in each object but have not been able to get the formula to update with additional entries.  The biggest downfall is that I have no programming background!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the site Ann! What data are you trying to pull into the object? Sounds like you need a roll-up summary field to work with, or failing that a trigger. A little more info on where exactly you're stuck wold facilitate some good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Given `Stock__c`, `Received_Packages__c` and `Shipped_Packages__c`, where the latter two are tied to a stock record (we will say that received is what you received, shipped is what you sent out), and the latter two objects have a master-detail relationship with the former, you can then simply use roll up summaries on `Stock__c` to determine total amounts received and shipped, which you can then use a formula (`Total_Received__c - Total_Shipped__c`) to determine the remaining stock levels (the on-hand quantity).